# Tools to perform benchmark of block/stream ciphers on Linux?

Tags: encryption, linux

I would like to perform some benchmarking of different block and stream ciphers for general data (lossless and lossy data) encryption and decryption (with focus on power consumption).

To get general idea, I guess it probably would be better to use existing tools than to implement everything myself. After that, I can implement certain ciphers myself to get better performance for specific cases.

Are there any tools that I can use for this initial benchmarking? Which tool support wider range of ciphers? The only options that I can think of right now are cryptsetup, TrueCrypt and openssl... but can I use disk encryption utilities to benchmark encryption and decryption for general data?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about benchmarking. The fact that cryptographic algorithms are being benchmarked is only incidental.

Comment: You can use any of these possibilities, I don't see the point of this question. A benchmark measures an implementation, not an algorithm. It's up to you to choose what you want to benchmark.